# Can a static method return new instances of an object?

Tags: c#, static

I have this static method, which purpose is to load the init values of a dictionary.
My concern with this method, is whether it keep creating a new instance every time it is being called,
or will reference the already created instance?

```
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GetCountryNamesCodes()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"AF", "Afghanistan"},
            {"Afghanistan", "AF"},
            {"YT", "Mayotte"},
            {"Mayotte", "YT"}
        };
}
```

Comment: the answer is in the code: it _returns_ a _new_ dictionary. (you could have checked, btw, by evaluating `GetCountryNamesCodes() == GetCountryNamesCodes()`) - if you want the method to always return _the same_ object, you need to store it in a (static) property.

Comment: This looks like you're wanting to return the same list of countries and their codes whenever GetCountryNamesCodes is called. Hardcoding them like this might not be an issue but what's your approach if the list changes?

Comment: It a static member with a lot of entries, like more thatn 500  entries, and just looks very bad to have this in the top of the class -  so having an method initalizing the member kind of hid the 500 entries from the top of the class. @sr28

Answer (score 1):

Your code will alway return a new instance of the dictionary. If you want to return always the same instance, create a class variable:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> countryNames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"AF", "Afghanistan"},
            {"Afghanistan", "AF"},
            {"YT", "Mayotte"},
            {"Mayotte", "YT"}
        };

public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GetCountryNamesCodes()
{
        return countryNames;
}
```

If creating the variable is more complicated, you can use a static constructor.